# Using walker to display all menu branches at once?

Tags: menus, walker

So i have need to get all submenus displayed at once on site and could use little help to customising walker for task.

Menu displayed like this:

```
menuitem1 menuitem2 menuitem3 menuitem4
 sub1.1    sub2.1    sub3.1    sub4.1
 sub1.2    sub2.2              sub4.2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is the example given a HTML a visual or a literal example? What problem does this solve?

Comment: As far as it is, no code yet, and looking even where to even start with actual issue, IE how to loop all branches open at once when any of menuitem is opened

Comment: I think you could just use some basic css to achieve that. For example when menu wrapper element is hovered then display:block; all submenus. Or attach a js eventListener to your menu to watch for hovers on menuitems and toggle active class to the whole menu to display the subitems.

Comment: +1 to CSS, I don't see the need for a walker here

Comment: prehaps to expand, this is for wordpress, not standard html site, using bootstrap ... there doesnt seem be any viable way do it css way